# NiFi Cluster content repo full on a node

Tags: apache-nifi

On our NiFi cluster, the content repo is full on one node (it is isolated on it's own disk so does not affect NiFi OS, etc.) and now it seems NiFi can not process any flowfiles that involve this node's content repo.  Once a node's content repo is full, is there a way to lower the usage below 100%.  Are we basically stuck with clearing out this node's flowfile and content repo?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could set `nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled` to off. That would prevent archiving unreferenced Content Claims.

However, there's not much you can do but get rid of irrelevant content as soon as possible. NiFi must have free content repository to work.